# Forest package: skipping empty nodes

Tags: tree, latex, tikz

Is there a way to have a line continue through an empty node in the Forest package?
For example, with the code below:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={align=left, 
        font=\footnotesize\sffamily, 
        anchor=west, grow'=0, edge=thick, 
        l sep+=6mm, s sep=0mm, tier/.pgfmath=level()},
        forked edges,
        [a
            [b
                [c 
                    [1 \\ 2]
                ]
                [d 
                    [3 \\ 4 \\ 5]
                ]
            ]
            [e
                [[ 6 \\ 7]]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}
```

the following figure is generated:

[image]

As you can see, I have no subcategories after "e". However, I do want the numbers to be aligned, so for now, I just included an empty node. Currently, some empty space is shown at the position of the node. Would it be possible to circumvent this "gap" and have a straight line from "e" to the numbers instead?

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly assign the same tier to the numbers and then leave out the extra level for `e`.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={align=left, 
        font=\footnotesize\sffamily, 
        anchor=west, grow'=0, edge=thick, 
        l sep+=6mm, s sep=0mm, tier/.pgfmath=level()},
        forked edges,
        [a
            [b
                [c 
                    [1 \\ 2, tier=number]
                ]
                [d 
                    [3 \\ 4 \\ 5, tier=number]
                ]
            ]
            [e
                [ 6 \\ 7, tier=number]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{Example}
    \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}
```

Result:

[image]